Passing request context from FastAPI to Microsoft Semantic Kernel Plugin for OpenAI Integration
I am integrating Microsoft Semantic Kernel with OpenAI in my FastAPI application. I have a chat/ endpoint where I receive a session_id from the request, and I need to pass this session_id to a plugin along with the openai_client. However, I'm unsure how to properly pass the session_id from the FastAPI request to the plugin inside the kernel's execution process.
Here is the relevant code for setting up the kernel and plugin:
# Kernel and service setup
kernel = Kernel()

execution_settings = AzureChatPromptExecutionSettings(tool_choice="auto")
execution_settings.function_choice_behavior = FunctionChoiceBehavior.Auto(filters={})

openai_client = OpenAI(api_key=api_key)
chat_completion_service = OpenAIChatCompletion(
                ai_model_id=model_id, 
                api_key=api_key, 
                service_id=service_id 
            )

# Add services and plugins
kernel.add_service(chat_completion_service) 
kernel.add_plugin(MovesPlugin(openai_client), plugin_name='MovesPlugin')

Inside my FastAPI endpoint, I want to pass the session_id to the plugin when calling the kernel for a chat response:
# Inside FastAPI endpoint
@app.post("/chat/")
async def chat(request: Request):
    session_id = await request.json().get('session_id')

    # Get chat completion service
    _chat_completion_service = kernel.get_service(type=ChatCompletionClientBase)
    
    # Get chat completion response
    response = await _chat_completion_service.get_chat_message_content(
        chat_history=chat_history,
        kernel=kernel,
        settings=execution_settings
    )
    
    return response

How can I pass the request context (session_id) from the FastAPI request to the MovesPlugin and make sure it is used correctly along with the openai_client inside the Semantic Kernel execution?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I fixed it somehow like, in the chat_history that I passed to get_chat_message_content(), it will have the System Prompt as it's first message. There i added the session_id at the end of the prompt mentioning it like My Session ID: {session_id}. Then I added the session_id parameter to the the methods which uses the session id in the MovesPlugin() like,
def generate_query(self, session_id, input_query):
    # generate query logic

When the kernel calls this method, automatically it passes the session_id which i already given in the System Prompt will be automatically passed to it and thus it solves the issue.
Note: This is a temporary solution to fix this issue. if anyone has a better solution to pass it directly as an argument to the plugin, you are most welcome.
